# Raising a BigInteger to a negative number

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
System.Numerics.BigInteger k = SomeBigInteger();
System.Numerics.BigInteger M;
M = System.Numerics.BigInteger.Pow(k,-1); 
Response.Write(+M);
```

However, this produces the error:

> The number must be greater than or equal to zero.Parameter name: exponent

How do I raise a `BigInteger` to a negative number?

Comment: Apparently a result from such an operation will remain integer in a very special case only. Do you understand the mathematical meaning of negative power?

Comment: isn't a negative power essentially a fraction.  What would you expect the answer to be if it needs to be expressed in an integer?

Comment: You'd have to convert to another type that can handle fractions first, like decimal, double or float.

Comment: How can i do fractions ?

Comment: @DanKaufman It's not immediately clear that `BigInteger.Pow()` *must* return an integer. It could, for example, return an arbitrarily large (or small, in this case) float/double. Personally, I'd expect it to return something along the lines of `1/k` rather than throwing an error.

Comment: Math.Pow() or System.Numerics.Pow() accepts positive exponent

Comment: i used 1/k and its result is 0

Comment: System.Numerics.Biginteger.Divide(1,k);

Comment: the question is can we raise negative exponent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raising `k` to the `-1`th power will result in `1/k`, which will be an integer only when `k` is 1. When `k` is greater than 1, the result will not be an integer, which is why `BigInteger.Pow()` doesn't support raising to negative powers.

Comment: It's also an integer if `k` is -1 ;)

Comment: @juharr touché :)

Comment: This doesn't really answer *how* to do it, rather, that the library doesn't support it. In this case, `BigInteger.Pow()` does return a `BigInteger`, but it wouldn't be impossible to return an arbitrarily small float/double, either. It may be potentially solvable using `BigInteger.DivRem()`, depending on how large OPs `k` is

Comment: let me put k=51 .... ok so BigInteger.DivRem(51,-1) or DivRem(1,51)or what?